# My application crashes when I press my signup Button

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

When i Run the application application is crashing (Did i written the code wrong)?

Here is my post:

```
public class SignUP extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


private EditText edtEmail,edtUserName, edtPassword;
private Button btnSignUp,btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edtEnterEmail);
    edtUserName = findViewById(R.id.edtUserName);
    edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtEnterPassword);
    btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnSignUp:

            final ParseUser appUser = new ParseUser();
            appUser.setEmail(edtEmail.getText().toString());
            appUser.setUsername(edtUserName.getText().toString());
            appUser.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
            appUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null){
                        FancyToast.makeText(SignUP.this,appUser.getUsername() + "is signed up",
                                FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, SUCCESS,true).show();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUP.this,LoginActicvity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        FancyToast.makeText(SignUP.this,"There was an error: "
                                + e.getMessage(),FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, ERROR,true).show();

                    }
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.btnLogin:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

This is My error when i try to run the application :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create() or the proper subclass.

Its showing like this.

Comment: Can you give us the line where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've initialized Parse in your Application class.

```
 // Register your parse models
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(GameScore.class); // for example

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(context)
                .applicationId(APPLICATION_ID)
                .server(SERVER)
                .build()
        );
```

And you also need to create a `ParseObject`  .

Comment: Also you need to register your parse objects to what it extends. For example if your new class extends from ParseUser, You should use ParseUser..registerSubclass(MyNewUserClass.class);